# AWS Storage Gateway - Problem with Serial Console - KVM Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, storage, virtualization, kvm

I've been trying to get the KVM of AWS-Storage Gateway working for a while now, but I can't get into the configuration because the Serial Console always hangs at "Escape character is [^]" and I don't get a login prompt.
According to "virsh ttyconsole" a pseudo console is available under /dev/pts/3.
Can anyone help me?

Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: varify inside the guest if tty console is setup properly. Otherwise use vnc